# Efficient use of CPU idle time for parallel URL processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing, cpu-usage

We have a job service in production server which is triggering during the interval of 2 minutes with the help of a timer. 
This service is collecting 20 tasks from database, then creates 20 URLs(same host with different parameters); fire them in parallel using thread pool threads, and wait for the response.
URLs are loop back. ie, destination website is also hosted in same Server.

**Process flow is follows:**

```
1. If task is simple, URL response will get back to job service within seconds. 
   But job service has to wait for another 2 minutes to pick next 20 jobs. 
   CPU will be idle here. 
   How we can efficiently utilize this CPU idle time for processing more jobs…?

2. If task is long running, job service will wait max 2 minutes 
   for the response, if not receiving a response; service will 
   pick next 20 jobs to process. As a result jobs will be queued up 
   and CPU usage will go very high. 
   How do we prevent such a situation….?
```

Instead of this timer and picking jobs in regular intervals, do we have any other efficient methods to process jobs..?
Like monitor IIS worker process and CPU usage, based on that pick jobs and process them…..
If so how we can monitor IIS worker process and CPU usage by using C# codes……?
Or any other thoughts.....Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Code snippet for creating parallel threads:

```
public class ParallelProcess
  {
    #region "Instance constructor"
    public ParallelProcess()
    {
      //Handle unhandled execeptions, throws from threads.
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    }
    #endregion

#region "Private Fields"

#region "Static"
//Number of threads to be activated to process each job request.
private static int MaxConcurrentThreads = 0;
//Minimum number of idle threads that should exist in the pool.
private static int ThreadBuffer = 0;
//Time out in ms for the theadpool to wait on all threads to complete.
private static int ThreadWaitTimeOut = 0;
//Available Worker Threads in thread pool
private static int workerThreads = 0;
//Available Port Threads in thread pool
private static int completionThreads = 0;
//Minimum Worker Threads available in ThreadPool
private static int minW = 0;
//Minimum Port Threads available in ThreadPool
#endregion
private static int minC = 0;

#endregion
 #region "static constructor"
    static ParallelProcess()
    {
      try
      {
        //Required threads defined in C:\HobooAppServer_Config\hobooAppServer_config.xml
        MaxConcurrentThreads = Configuration.RequiredThread;
        ThreadBuffer =Configuration.ThreadBuffer;
        //In milliseconds
        ThreadWaitTimeOut =Configuration.TRWaitTime;
         //In milliseconds

         //Get min number of threads from thread pool.
         ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(minW, minC);

         //set the thead limit to spawn in the current thread pool.
         if (minW >= MaxConcurrentThreads)
         {
          ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(MaxConcurrentThreads, minC);
          minW = MaxConcurrentThreads;
         }
        else
        {
          ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(minW, minC);
        }

        }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        //Write exception to log file.
        WriteJobLog(new JobLogDTO
        {
          Mode = "Parallel",
          UniqueId = "Thread Pool Exception",
          ThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(),
          StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
          ExceptionOrResult = ex.ToString()
        });

      }
    }
    #endregion


#region "public methods"
/// <summary>
/// Gets the count of rows to be retrieved from job.
/// This takes into account the current work load and available threads to process.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>int (Number of threads currently available)</returns>
private int GetMaxItemsRetrievalCount()
{
  int rtnVal = 1;
  try
  {
    //Get Available idle threads currently in the thead pool.
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(workerThreads, completionThreads);
    rtnVal = workerThreads > MaxConcurrentThreads ? MaxConcurrentThreads : workerThreads;
    rtnVal = rtnVal > 0 ? rtnVal : 0;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Write exceptions to log file.
    WriteJobLog(new JobLogDTO
    {
      Mode = "Parallel",
      UniqueId = "GetMaxItemsRetrievalCount Exception",
      ThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(),
      StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
      ExceptionOrResult = ex.ToString()
    });
  }
  return rtnVal;
}

/// <summary>
/// The method which processes jobs on worker threads.
/// </summary>
public void ProcessBatchJobs(bool pIsNight, bool plPriority, string pUniqueId)
{
  bool isContinue = true;
  int maxRecordCount = 0;
  ManualResetEvent[] signalEvents = null;

  do
  {
    maxRecordCount = GetMaxItemsRetrievalCount();
    if (maxRecordCount > 0)
    {
      //Pick jobs from database
      List<SnapShotTask> Jobs =Business.Rtds.SnapShot.PickTasks(pIsNight, plPriority);
      if (Jobs != null && Jobs.Count > 0)
      {
        //Log Header-Thread Pool Information And Statistics - In Parallel Threads
        WriteJobLog(new JobLogDTO
        {
          Mode = "Parallel",
          UniqueId = pUniqueId,
          ThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(),
          StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
          AvblWorkerThread = workerThreads.ToString(),
          AvblPortThread = completionThreads.ToString(),
          AcqrdWorkerThread = minW.ToString(),
          AcqurdPortThread = minC.ToString(),
          JobsToProcess = Jobs.Count.ToString()
        });

        signalEvents = new ManualResetEvent[Jobs.Count];
        int signalCount = 0;

        //Loop through each job, create call back function, add items to queue, fire them
        foreach (SnapShotTask job in Jobs)
        {
          signalEvents(signalCount) = new ManualResetEvent(false);
          BatchCallBack threadPoolCallBack = 
           new BatchCallBack(job, signalEvents(signalCount));
          bool nResult = 
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
           new WaitCallback(threadPoolCallBack.ThreadPoolCallback),
           new BatchThreadData
          {
            IsNight = pIsNight,
            UniqueId = pUniqueId
          });
          signalCount += 1;
        }

        //Wait here untill child threads finish the job or timeout meets.
        bool result = WaitHandle.WaitAll(signalEvents, ParallelProcess.ThreadWaitTimeOut);

        //When one or more threads have not set the signal.
        if (result == false)
        {
          //Logger.Write("Not all threads completed in the pool. 
          //The pool exited due to time-out.");
        }
        else
        {
          //Logging time taken per batch.
          //Logger.Write(string.Format("Average Time taken for each batch of {1} orders : {0} ms",
          //New TimeSpan((ticksEnd - ticksStart)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
        }
        //ticksEnd = DateTime.Now.Ticks
      }
      else
      {
        //TODO : Retry Logic
        //Nothing to process.
        isContinue = false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      //We did not get a thread to execute. So wait for a free thread(s).
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
  } while (isContinue);

  //end time after batch is done.
  //endTime = DateTime.Now
  //Log the over-all time taken.
}
/// <summary>
/// Log unhandled exceptions from this application domain if any.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
  //Write unhandled exception to log file.
  WriteJobLog(new JobLogDTO
  {
    Mode = "Parallel",
    UniqueId = "UnhandledException",
    ThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(),
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
    ExceptionOrResult = ex.ToString()
  });
}
#endregion
}
```

Comment: I would collect some data for CPU usage over a couple of days for several scenarios (playing around with the timer interval and the number of tasks). It should be enough to set up a configuration which will give you significant improvement. Then, you could go further and keep the interval and the number of tasks as application variables which you could adjust after each batch of tasks is processed.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. We tried this scenario. Set the timer value and number of jobs as application variable and put in configuration file and monitor the CPU performance over hours by changing the values. But looks challenging and sees CPU usage as waves since some of the jobs are long running takes much time and some are simple jobs finishes in seconds.

Comment: Can you post some code from the section where you create the parallel threads?

Comment: Off topic: do you really need to use the ASP .Net application? Do you retrieve and include some external information in the URL responses? Isn't there any viable alternative so that the job service will work only with the database server (if the data content is served only from this source)?

Comment: @Alex: Code snippet for createing paralle threads is attached in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to monitor CPU load, as the OS does it for you. It will schedule threads depending on their priority.

Set the thread of your tasks to a lower priority. Doing so, these tasks will be delayed until the CPU is free to execute the less important threads.

Set the priority like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadPriority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal; // Or ThreadPriority.Lowest.
```